# Signal x cannot be synthesized, bad synchrononous description

Tags: vhdl

I'm very new to vhdl and i cannot manage to find what's causing this error. 
I'm trying to replicate the functionality of a CD54/74HC192 Circuit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity upg1 is
    Port ( clock_up : in  std_logic;
           clock_down : in  std_logic;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           asyn_load : in  STD_LOGIC;
           bcd_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           bcd_ut : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           term_up : out  STD_LOGIC;
           term_down : out  STD_LOGIC);
end upg1;

architecture Behavioral of upg1 is
subtype state_type is integer range 0 to 15;
signal next_state, present_state: state_type;
signal clock : std_logic;

begin

process(clock_up, clock_down)
begin
   if clock_up = '1' then
      clock <= clock_down;
    else
      if clock_down = '1' then
      clock <= clock_up;
   end if;
   end if;
end process;


process(present_state, asyn_load, clock) -- line 65
begin
   if reset= '1' then
      next_state <= 0;
   end if;
   if (asyn_load = '1' and (rising_edge(clock))) then
         if present_state = 9 or present_state = 13 or present_state = 15 then
         present_state <= 0;
         elsif
         present_state = 10 or present_state = 12 or present_state = 14 then
         present_state <= 9;
         elsif
         present_state = 11 then
         present_state <= 4;
         else
         present_state <= present_state + 1;
         end if;

       else
         if rising_edge(clock) then 
            if present_state = 12 then
            present_state <= 3;
            elsif present_state = 13 then
            present_state <= 4;
            elsif present_state = 14 then
            present_state <= 5;
            elsif present_state = 15 then
            present_state <= 6;
            elsif present_state = 0 then
            present_state <= 9;
            else
            present_state <= present_state - 1;
            end if;
     else
      present_state <= TO_INTEGER(UNSIGNED(bcd_in));
   end if; 
   end if;

end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I've tried different methods in resolving the error but unable to do so.

Error-console:

```
line 65: Signal present_state cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description. The description style you are using to describe a synchronous element (register, memory, etc.)
```

Comment: There are loads of answers to this exact error, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vhdl]+bad+synchronous+description

Comment: i've read them, but none of them has contributed to any solution.

Comment: Three of the first 4 results answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use both packages `numeric_std` and `std_logic_arith/unsigned`, but use only `numeric_std` since this is a VHDL standard package, where `std_logic_arith/unsigned` are Synopsys proprietary.  So change to:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
```

About the real issue, then create state in VHDL through flip-flops using a structure like:

```
process(clock, reset)
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then
    ...
  end if;
  if reset = '1' then
    ...
  end if;
end if;
```

Synthesis will recognize this and infer flip-flops.  The `reset` and `clock` should not be used elsewhere inside the process.

Comment: I've not seen this coding style for an asynchronous reset, though it makes sense.  Looking at the Xilinx synthesis guide, the recommended method is to use an `if`/`elsif` pair, with the ansynchronous sets/clear in the `if` and the clocking in the `elsif`.  Does this style work with other synthesizers/libraries?

Comment: If multiple flip-flops (FFs) are inferred through the `if/elsif` with reset in `if`, then all the FFs must be reset, since the non-included FFs are otherwise not clocked if reset is asserted, which does not match FF behavior, e.g. `if reset = '1' then a <= '0' elsif rising_edge(clock) then a <= '1'; b <= a; end if;`.  If splitting the reset and clock in two `if`, then there is not this dependency, and having reset last means it takes precedence, just like in the FF.  This works for Altera, Xilinx, and Lattice.

Comment: @MortenZilmer For the use case of some FF's reset and others not reset, this makes sense.  But I would argue for separate processes, rather than a single process with different reset behavior for each inferred FF.  But an interesting case.  Thanks.

Comment: @PlayDough: It is usually convenient to keep for example data and valid in the same process, since it makes reading the code easier and the flow is often very similar.  But in this case only the valid indication should be reset, since it increases the probability of catching bugs where undefined data is used since X value may propagate.

Comment: @MortenZilmer Well, that's a style question, of which there are many a religious battle. :)  And I agree 100% on limiting resets to control and status signals, not data.  Now, if I could just convince the powers-that-be in-house that signal initialization is a Bad Thing for the very same reason...

Comment: @PlayDough if you are only targeting an FPGA fabric that does support initialisation 'for free', then I would say that it can be a useful construct, in some cases saving logic resource, increasing performance, or both.

Comment: @scary_jeff Sure, the initialization can save some reset logic. But 1) we've always required an external reset that doesn't initiate a reconfig and 2) it can mask data flow problems in simulation by eliminating U propagation. It is a feature I find to have little value.

Comment: @PlayDough if your target hardware supports initialisation, then this can become a solution to unknown state propagation because you can make it impossible to be in an unknown state. I don't mean to argue, I just wanted to add some balance to the 'initialisation is a Bad Thing™' statement; I completely agree that it *can* be bad in some scenarios, but like most things, it has its place.

Comment: @scary_jeff I don't mean that the FPGA itself can never be in an unknown state.  Indeed, logic will always be a 0 or 1 (or in transition).  What I mean is that it can be very difficult to determine if some intermediate signal is not properly initialized in simulation, and U propagation is an excellent way to determine if one is not properly managing inputs that are assumed invalid.  And when I said that I find signal initialization to have little value, I didn't mean no value.  But I think by default signals should not be initialized, and exceptions need to be properly justified.