# Near Text "Process" expected "IF"

Tags: vhdl, hdl, quartus

I know this question has been answered some times already, but all those answers are specific to the according code.
That's why I am asking it again. Why do I get this error and how do I fix it.
I am trying to make a 8-bit up/down counter.

The error:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at UpDownCounter.vhd(30) near text
>   "PROCESS";  expecting "if"

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;      -- needed for arithmetic increment
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

ENTITY UpDownCounter IS
port( inA, inB : IN STD_LOGIC ;
        Max_count: IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
        result : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0)
);
END UpDownCounter;

Architecture behavior of UpDownCounter is
signal internal_result : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
result <= internal_result;
    PROCESS(inA, inB)
        BEGIN
            IF (inA'EVENT and inA = '1') THEN
                IF internal_count < Max_count THEN
                    internal_result <= internal_result + 1;
                END IF;
            ELSIF (inB'EVENT and inB = '1') THEN
                        -- Check for maximum count
                IF internal_count > Max_count THEN
                    internal_result <= internal_result - 1;
                END IF;
            ELSE                
                    internal_result <= "00000000";
    END PROCESS;    
END behavior;
```

The help is appreciated!

Comment: You're missing the end if for the outer if statement in your process. The message is telling you it expects an `END IF;` to delimit the outer if statement. Instead it found `END PROCESS;` (which is also required to delimit the process statement).

Comment: Answering syntax error questions can lack utility when uncovering further errors. In this case trying to use two clocks to operate the same sequential logic in synthesis.

Comment: Are the inA and InB clocks?, If so do not use them in same process as user1155120 says also use rising_edge() instead if you plan to simulated it. If they are signals (not dedicated clocks) do not use the 'EVENT attribute.

Comment: And you could note if inA and inB are not clocks then as latch enables you would be creating gate oscillators with the expressions `internal_result <= internal_result + 1;` and `internal_result <= internal_result - 1;`. (The want to be clocks, the proper way to deal with them is to OR them together as in a [74192](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXjXm.jpg) or use a direction and a clock). See [Signal x cannot be synthesized, bad synchrononous description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387255/signal-x-cannot-be-synthesized-bad-synchrononous-description/37517007#37517007).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the final ELSE is missing the terminating END IF.

This is for the previous ELSE IF and it's corresponding IF which must have an END IF; statement.